# Does the n >> p holds also for minibatches

Tags: neural-networks, model, perceptron

It's pretty known that when dealing with models (without regularization) the main assumption is $n >> p$ where $p$ is the number of features in the dataset

Let's suppose that we have 1.000.000 samples with 500 features. Then, the closed form of the perceptron/linear regression is valid since $X$ is most likely invertible.

However, calculating the inverse and the matrix multiplication might be very expensive in this case, so suppose that we than approach the problem from a numerical optimization approximation using minibatch SGD (for example as we would do with Keras)

It's known that there is no magic trick to find the size of the minibatch, however I would like to know if, in order to have good approximation, the $n >>p$ should hold also for the minibatch, so that the solutions estimated on the minibatches are relatively close one to the other, and so it's able to lead to the solution

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe that this question arises from a misunderstanding about how neural networks are estimated compared to regression models. Consider the example of an OLS regression. In the OLS regression, the parameters can be estimated in one step using the normal equations $\hat \beta = (X^T X)^{-1}X^T y$ (but in practice, SVD or QR decompositions are used to improve precision). The normal equations (or QR, or SVD) require a certain matrix to be full-rank matrix so that the regression coefficients are identified.

These facts about OLS regression are not relevant to a neural network because training a neural network with gradient descent mini-batching does not involve solving a linear system involving the design matrix $X$. The gradient descent update of the model parameters $\theta$ has the form

$$
\theta^{(i+1)} =\theta^{(i)} - \eta\nabla L( f(X),y | \theta^{(i)})
$$
where $\eta$ is the learning rate and $ L( f(X),y | \theta^{(i)})$ is the loss for the mini-batch computed with the current parameters $\theta^{(i)}$ and $f$ is the network's predictions.

For the common NN losses that I'm familiar with, there is no component of computing the gradient which requires inverting a matrix formed from $X$.

A common scenario for mini-batch SGD is using a single sample $n=1$ in each mini-batch. If it were true that mini-batch gradient descent required $n > p$, then these neural networks would be restricted to only utilizing $p = 0 < 1 = n$ features, which is clearly a very restrictive requirement!

---

As an aside, you do not have to have $n > p$ to estimate a regression (even without regularization). As an example, you can directly apply (mini-batch or batch) gradient descent to a rank-deficient design matrix, and you will be able to estimate coefficients. However, you are giving up *identifiability* because there are many vectors of coefficients that obtain the least loss in this setting, and this procedure only finds one such vector.

Comment: sure, the gradient estimation has nothing to do with batch, however, seeing how SGD is implemented on minibatch (or even SVRG or other stochastic GD algorithm), they perform some optimization over a single minibatch (I mean, SGD samples like 100 times from the same minibatch), and then they pass to the next minibatch... my question is then, isn't this "optimizing the single minibatch for many iteration" influenced by the fact that a overparameterized NN might just perfectly optimize the minibatch each time, and therefore never reach the "whole" loss minimum?

Comment: Doing several optimization steps using a single mini-batch will behave differently than using a new mini-batch at each time step, but this seems like an entirely different question.

Comment: Mh makes sense, however that was actually my questions, maybe I'm not the best at asking questions ahah